# Wired "empty" element inside my array after using splice

Tags: javascript

I use an `data` object  to store and remove blobs using `data.instructAudios = [];`

When I use `splice` to remove specific blob by its `index` like:

```
data.instructAudios.splice(index, 1);
```

I get a wired log with empty element in the array!!!

[image]

**What is this and how can I remove blobs by their index without this bug?**

Comment: Are you sure there was no `empty` before `.splice()`?

Comment: let me check that agian... I don't know what empty means here?

Comment: @SaraRee can you show me your initial array you're trying to splice?

Comment: Sorry this is caused by adding element in index 2 in a empty array...

Comment: @SaraRee `empty` is produced when you create an array with `Array(n)` or set the `length`, for example `myArray.length = 100` - you'll get some `empty` values at the end if the array was shorter than `100` before that.

Comment: @SaraRee yeah, makes sense - this will cause `empty` elements in between too.

Comment: In Firefox it is refered as `<1 empty slots>` , `<2 empty slots>` ... and e.t.c. which I think is better way to describe one or more unset entries.